# Is it possible to make Google Drive folders available offline?

Tags: file-management, google-drive, offline

Can I create folders that can sync with Google Drive similar to Windows?

Actually I have to store some files offline in multiple phones, tablets, and computers. I'm fine with the Windows version of Google Drive: it stores files offline too.

Is there any way to do the same for Android?

Answer (score 1):

To a certain degree, yes it can be done. It's easy if you are only concerned about a limited number of files.

For a single file, while connected to Google Drive on your phone, browse to your intended file, then click the right menu and choose the option "**Available offline**"

In general, you can also change the caching on your Google Drive app by going to "**Settings > Cache Size**" and increase it to the maximum available. I believe it's 1000MB at the moment.